# How to consume only latest offset in Kafka topic

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am working on a scala application in which I am using kafka. My kafka consumer code is as follows.

```scala
def getValues(topic: String): String  = {
        
  val props = new Properties()
  props.put("group.id", "test")
  props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer") 
  props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
  props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")
  val consumer: KafkaConsumer[String, String] = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)

  val topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, 0)
  consumer.assign(util.Collections.singletonList(topicPartition))
  val offset = consumer.position(topicPartition) - 1
  val record = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500)).asScala
  for (data <- record)
    if(data.offset() == offset) val value = data.value()
  return value
}
```

In this I just want to return latest value. When I run my application I get following log:

```
 Resetting offset for partition topic-0 to offset 0
```

Because of which `val offset = consumer.position(topicPartition) - 1` becomes -1 and data.offset() gives list of all offsets. And as a result I don't get the latest value. Why it is automatically resetting offset to 0? How can I correct it? What is the mistake in my code? or anyother way I can get the value from the latest offset?

Comment: How much elements does your topic typically contains ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `seek` method which - according to the [JavaDocs](https://docs.confluent.io/5.5.0/clients/javadocs/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#seek-org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition-long-) - "overrides the fetch offsets that the consumer will use on the next poll(timeout)".

Also make sure that you are setting

```scala
props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
```

Making those two amendments to your code, the following worked for me to only fetch the `value` of the latest offset of the partion `0` in the selected topic:

```scala
import java.time.Duration
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition
import collection.JavaConverters._

def getValues(topic: String): String  = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put("group.id", "test")
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
    props.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest")
    val consumer: KafkaConsumer[String, String] = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](props)

    val topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, 0)
    consumer.assign(java.util.Collections.singletonList(topicPartition))
    val offset = consumer.position(topicPartition) - 1
    consumer.seek(topicPartition, offset)
    val record = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500)).asScala
    for (data <- record) {
      val value: String = data.value() // you are only reading one message if no new messages flow into the Kafka topic
    }
    value
}
```

Comment: This will only work if the topic has a single partition though.

Comment: The OP was deliberately defining the topic partition as `TopicPartition(topic, 0)`, so that should not be a problem here @C4stor?

Comment: Anyway, good point and will make it clear in my answer. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: Well, I don't know ^^ since the OP code is not working in the first place, I don't know which parts are bugs and which parts are assumptions ^^

Answer (score 0):

In this line, `props.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")`, you set the parameter `auto.offset.reset` of your Kafka consumer to `earliest`, which will reset the offset to earliest. If you want the latest value, you should use `latest` instead.
You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#auto.offset.reset).

Comment: but with latest I can get values which I send when consumer is up. I already have data in kafka topic. I just need to consume the one which came latest. How can I do that?